# How can I construct a reusable DateTime object in CL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I have been trying to construct a `DateTime object` in CodeIgniter. I am loading it from the from the library. But I can't seem a way to construct a DateTime() with a given $time_zone param.

The only way I can see this happening is by adding the DateTime object in all methods.

This is a big drawback using the mvc. Does anyone have an alternative?

**My code:**

```
class Create_Timestamp 
{
     private $date_time;

     /**
     * @param $time_zone : gets passed in from a cookie. Cookie value is an array that gets retrieved from the DB. In the
     * array there time zone value
     * @return int
     */

     public function __construct($time_zone)
     {
         $this->date_time = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
     }

     public function TimeStamp()
     {
       $time_stamp =  $this->date_time->getTimestamp();
       return $time_stamp;
      }

      public function convertTimeStamp($unix_time_stamp)
      {
           fb($unix_time_stamp);
           $this->date_time->createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $unix_time_stamp);
           //$this->date_time->setTimestamp($unix_time_stamp);
           $formatted_time_stamp = $this->date_time->format("m/d/Y h:i:s A");
    return $formatted_time_stamp;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please remember to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel do PIE (Proudly Invented Elsewhere). You'll save yourself and others a lot of grief.

Take for instance [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com) package.

If you're lucky enough to use CI v.3 just go to your application folder and do

```
$ composer require nesbot/carbon
```

and start using it

```php
Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($time_stamp, $time_zone)->toDateTimeString();
```

If  you're using CI v.2.X still **leverage composer**. Go to your app root and do

```
$ composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Then in your `index.php` add

```php
require './vendor/autoload.php'; // or whatever the path would be in your case
```